# Layout change: VisualStateManager and DockPanel's children's Dock direction?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'd like to change the layout of my application depending on the size of its window: it can be split either horizontally or vertically. I want to use `VisualStateManager` for the purpose of resizing the components of the UI.

What is the best control to use to build the region of the UI that needs to toggle between vertical and horizontal split?

DockPanel seems like an almost obvious choice, but while you can change the side a child docks to by using `DockPanel.SetDock(UIElement, Dock)`, it seems impossible to do so in a VisualStyle.

Currently I use

```
VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, StandardHorizontal.Name, false);
DockPanel.SetDock(Browser, System.Windows.Controls.Dock.Left);
DockPanel.SetDock(Content, System.Windows.Controls.Dock.Right);
```

And the likes in my `SizeChanged` event handler. Is this the only way? Also, should I call `SetDock()` before `GoToState()` or after?

Edit: fixed mistype in the class name.

Comment: You mean `VisualStateManager`? If you used XAML could show you how to do it.

Comment: @ChrisW., yes, I mistyped it there. I use XAML layouts, but SetDock is a method so it's impossible to use Keyframes to set it.

I've actually switched to Grid now and just move the child between 0,1 and 1,0.